# Setting fdm=marker in the first line of .vimrc

Tags: vim

This is the first line of my `.vimrc` file:

```
" vim:fdm=marker " Treat comments as folds
```

Every time I edit `.vimrc` I get this error (and no other errors):

```
"~/.vimrc" 409L, 12674C
Error detected while processing modelines:
line    1:
E518: Unknown option: "
```

Since I have taken this line from some other `.vimrc`, it should work in my setup as well. Why doesn't it? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modeline syntax is wrong. I doubt it worked in the vimrc you copied it from. If you read `:h modeline` you will find that the modeline is trying to interpret the second quote as an option. Since there is no option called quote it fails.

You should use the second modeline syntax if you want to put a comment after the modeline and get something like the following

```
" vim: set fdm=marker: " Treat comments as folds
```

---

`:h modeline` copied below.

```
                                        modeline vim: vi: ex: E520
There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:
        [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

[text]                  any text or empty
{white}                 at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}          the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]                 optional white space
{options}               a list of option settings, separated with white space
                        or ':', where each part between ':' is the argument
                        for a ":set" command (can be empty)

Examples:
   vi:noai:sw=3 ts=6
   vim: tw=77

The second form (this is compatible with some versions of Vi):

        [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]

[text]                  any text or empty
{white}                 at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}     the string "vi:", "vim:", "Vim:" or "ex:"
[white]                 optional white space
se[t]                   the string "set " or "se " (note the space); When
                        "Vim" is used it must be "set".
{options}               a list of options, separated with white space, which
                        is the argument for a ":set" command
:                       a colon
[text]                  any text or empty
```